# Windows could not set up internet connection sharing (ICS)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, internet-sharing

I am trying to make an ad-hoc network. I think it was created succesfully, but when I tryd to turn internet sharing on I get this error `Windows could not set up internet connection sharing (ICS)`

I searched on google what is ICS and I found that it was an option in sharing tab in my connection properties, so I tried to enable it and I got this error

`An error occurred while internet connection sharing was being enabled. The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion.`

I tried to also look up google for solution for this and I ended up with nothing really, I tried to enable the required services @ `services.msc` for it.. rebooted and still same thing

**It was working a while ago**  (*had a problem at enabling my wireless for about 2 months and I just found a solution for it..*) **for some reason it doesn't now**

Comment: i kinda solved this by fixing firewall, it was based on firewall's problem for a missing service (Security Center).. Not sure tho, i was digging around the other problems that might have caused this and after fixing firewall i was able to enable the option ^^